# Confused about how to properly set and use associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following 3 models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  has_one :metric, dependent: :destroy
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :insight_key_phrases, dependent: :destroy
end

class InsightKeyPhrase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :metric
end
```

And I'm trying to create a cron job that runs every minute, grab all posts without metrics and, well... calculate the metrics:

```
class AnalysisJob < ApplicationJob

  def make_analyses(posts)
    posts.each do |p|
      begin
        metric = post.create_metric
        # I can't create the metric.insight_key_phrases here
      rescue
        metric.destroy!
    end
  end
end
```

I'm stuck. The `post.create_metric` creates a metric, but I can't access `metric.insight_key_phrases`:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'insight_key_phrases.metric_id' in 'where clause')
```

And if I try to destroy the `metric`, the same error is going to be raised:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'insight_key_phrases.metric_id' in 'where clause')
```

Clearly I'm making a mistake or misunderstanding something, I just don't know what.

Comment: Could this issue be related with `dependent: :destroy`?

Comment: do you have a `metric_id` column on your `insight_key_phrases` table?

Comment: I actually have a `metrics_id`, that's weird.

Comment: But why the hell it's generating the table with a `metrics_id`?

Comment: You tried calling metric.create_insight_key_phrase, correct?

Comment: @TedTran2019 No, that's `undefined`.

Comment: So you called calling  metric.create_insight_key_phrase and you got nil? Or it raised an error?

Comment: It raised an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method `create_insight_key_phrase' for #<Metric:0x00007f8c1a1fba28>)`

Comment: So, it turns out that the table was being generated with a column `metrics_id` because the migration was wrong: `t.belongs_to :metrics, null: false`

Comment: I've changed it to `t.belongs_to :metric` and now it's working.

Comment: I suggest you read the rails guide on associations https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, it's really good and it describes models configuration, migrations, options, etc